# Maclaurin series remainder in Ordo-form

Tags: taylor-expansion

I encountered a problem where two of the terms are the following:
$$ \cdots+\frac{1}{2!}(x-\frac{x^3}{3!} + \omicron(x^5))^2 + \frac{1}{3!}(x-\frac{x^3}{3!} + \omicron(x^5))^3 $$

It's suggested that the first term is equal to $ \frac{x^2}{2} + \omicron(x^4) $, and the second term is equal to $ \frac{x^3}{3!} + \omicron(x^5) $ without doing any hairy calculation. I don't see directly how you can go from the problem to the solutions. I get that you distribute the $ \frac{1}{2!} $ and $ \frac{1}{3!} $, but what happened with each $x$-term inside the brackets?

Comment: To derive it (and to understand it better) try to multiply out $(x-x^3/6 + o(x^5))^2$ and use that $x^n\cdot o(x^m) = o(x^{n+m})$ togeather with $o(x^n) + o(x^m) = o(x^n)$ if $n<m$ (a bigger exponent means the term goes quicker to zero when $x$ goes to zero).

Comment: @Winther Yeah, all of the "ordo" symbols are supposed to be capital "big O", I wasn't sure how to do that in code, so just used omicron. I will try out what you suggested!

Comment: @Winther Ok, I expanded the first part and got the following result: $ \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{6} + \frac{x^6}{72} + O(x^6) $. So what happens to the other two fractions? And also I got $ O(x^6) $ instead of $ O(x^4) $.

Comment: Looks good. The term $O(x^6) + x^6/72 = O(x^6)$ so you simplify this. The other terms you get when expanding the product are $O (x^8) $ and $O (x^10) $ so you have correctly neglected them.

Comment: @Winther Ok but then I still get $ O(x^6) $ and left with one term $ -x^4 / 6 $. Am I missing something?

Comment: My original comment was a bit inaccurate so I removed it, I should clarify what I meant. What you have written originally is formally correct in the sense that $\frac{1}{2}(x-x^3/3! + O(x^5))^2$ is equal to $x^2/2  + O(x^4)$. However as you have shown above we also have $(x-x^3/3! +O(x^5))^2 = x^2/2 - x^4/6 + O(x^6)$. This latter equality (which is the best one possible) is a stronger result as the error term have as larger exponent. In general you should present the result with as good error term as possible thus the result you got above is the one you should go with.

Comment: @Winther Oh ok, I think I understand now, so technically, the answer suggested in the question and the answer I got in the comment are both correct, but the one in the comment are more accurate.

Comment: @Winther Just something I wonder, is there a way or trick to determine the answer fast? Because the answersheet says that you should avoid doing any hairy calculation, so I was wondering if you could jump from the question to the answer (the ones in the question) directly? For example, the third term where you have a 3rd polynomial, what happens if you have higher? Could you "see" the answer quickly without expanding.

Comment: Exactly. To compute (the first term) fast/smartly one can first compute the error term which will be "error term" $\cdot$ "smallest term" which is $O(x^5)\cdot x = O(x^6)$ which can be combined with computing $(x-x^3/3!)^2$. For the next term since you already know $\frac{1}{2}(x-x^3/3! + O(x^5))^2$ you simply need to compute $\frac{1}{3}\cdot (x-x^3+O(x^5)) \cdot (x^2/2 - x^4/6 + O(x^6))$. This can again be used to compute higher order terms recursively. I doubt there is a much faster way than this (but I could be wrong).

Comment: @Winther Ok, thank you very much for you help! Much appreciated!